# How do I made Revolution Slider background image size responsive to screen size

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a clients website using the Revolution Slider plugin. I'm trying to optimise the page for mobile page speed.

Each slide is just a background image. The problem is that the image is 1920x1080 which is the same image used on mobile screens that are 640px wide or less. This makes the page load a larger file image then is needed.

I've tried removing the background image and including 2 versions of the image to the slide on their own layers. One layer only shows for mobile and the other only for desktop but even though it doesn't display both images it still loads them both. The mobile view shows the smaller image but still loads the larger one without using it.

Wordpress creates small, medium, large and thumbnail versions of images uploaded to the media library. I thought the plugin would use these by default for different screen sizes but I can't see how to set this or do it manually.

Is there a way for me to have the smaller image file display for smaller screens without loading the larger image file? If not is there another slider WordPress plugin that can do this?